# Mongoose: Property 'methods' does not exist on type 'Schema'. Did you mean 'method'?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Suddenly my code started throwing errors regarding methods on mongoose schema.

I have the following Document and Schema

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    domainId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    scope: string,
    tc: boolean,
    newsletter: boolean
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    domainId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Domain',
        required: true
    },
    scope: {
        type: UserScopes,
        required: true
    },
    verified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    tc: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    newsletter: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    strict: true
});

userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    var object = this.toObject();
    delete object.password;
    delete object.__v;

    object.id = object._id;
    delete object._id;

    return object;
}

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.get('password'), salt);
    
    this.set('password', hashedPassword);

    next();
});

userSchema.methods.comparePasswords = async function (triedPassword: string, savedPassword: string) {
    const result = await bcrypt.compare(triedPassword, savedPassword);
    return result;
}

userSchema.index({
    email: 1,
    domainId: 1
}, { unique: true });

const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc>('User', userSchema);

export { User };
```

Everything was working just fine an hour ago, but after a restart of the code, I get the following errors:

```js
src/models/user.ts(55,4): error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.
  => This relates to timestamps and strict settings.

src/models/user.ts(60,12): error TS2551: Property 'methods' does not exist on type 'Schema'. Did you mean 'method'?
  => This relates to toJSON method.

src/models/user.ts(77,5): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
  => This relates to the call made to next inside pre('save').

src/models/user.ts(80,12): error TS2551: Property 'methods' does not exist on type 'Schema'. Did you mean 'method'?
  => This relates to comparePasswords method.
```

I have no idea what is causing the issue.

MENTION: I am running the application using Docker, and I've also tried compiling with an older version of mongoose, and with the latest version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Today mongoose has released a new version and removed many of functionalities. I suggest to use older version of mongoose. Please share package.json so that I can specify the version.

Comment: if i downgrade mongoose with a few versions it woks, but it seems so weird, because in the documentation of the newest versions, it looks like it should work without breaking anything as it is now.

Comment: No need to downgrade version. Just mention "mongoose": "~5.x.xx", in your package.json. Just change ^ to ~ there. It will fi the issue.